# Microsoft Band SDK on Windows 10 - how to test sample files

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, microsoft-band

I wanted to test some the samples provided w/MS Band SDK.  Using nuget.exe from command prompt, installed MS Band SDK (1.3.10702).  Ran debug on custompages.shared/mainpage.cs and get error "property 'program' is missing or empty".

I am new to this, but would like to learn...appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you share some of the code you've written?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Windows, you'll have to open the [samples provided with the SDK](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK) using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, the [Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is free. These are Windows and Windows Phone projects, not Console projects that you can run from the command line.